# OS Grid reference control clash with version 6.3.1

Tags: javascript, openlayers, grids-graticules

I would like to implement the OS Grid reference control, which is here:

http://eap.ucr.ac.cr/mapas/ol-ext-master/examples/canvas/map.control.gridreference.html

I have modified the code for my needs, which eventually looks like this:

```
  var grids;
  grids = new ol.control.GridReference(
  { extent: [ -107000, 6770000, -87000, 6752500 ],
   size: [18,18]
   });
   map.addControl (grids);
```

but unfortunately they don't work at all with my current version of OpenLayers which is 6.3.1.
It was working for openlayers 5.3.0, but for version 6 it comes with nothing.
When I launch the map I see, that the grids are loaded, but suddenly they become overlapped with the map canvas. Some features already provided don't work properly or are gone.

Can someone explain to me what is the reason behind it?

I tried also the Graticule control tool and it looks exactly the same.

http://eap.ucr.ac.cr/mapas/ol-ext-master/examples/canvas/map.control.graticule.html

The console says nothing. I just can see some hidden elements, which number increases as I click on some object in order to trigger information pop-up.

You will see my full problem by looking at this test website here:

http://test.mkrgeo-blog.com/

where the map has been based.

Is there any way to marriage the OS Grid control with the most up-to-date OpenLayers version?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

After application proper ol-ext files, I could display the grids on my map. Unfortunately, they still seem to crash with some existing features.
I have an error in my console, which points:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFeatures')**

showing at the;

```
     map.addControl (grids);
```

[image]

Is there any way to fix it?

The link to full map is here:

http://test.mkrgeo-blog.com/

Comment: You may need to use a more recent version of OpenLayers.  The example you linked http://eap.ucr.ac.cr/mapas/ol-ext-master/examples/canvas/map.control.gridreference.html is using the latest version of OpenLayers (currently v6.9.0)

Comment: Nope, still the same mate. They were working for 5.3.0.

Comment: For me OS Grid reference control example worked OK with OL 6.3.1. You might have some old version of `ol.ext` library.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't suppose, that ol-ext has versions too. I have updated it, but some errors still come.

Comment: As several times in the past, you are again loading some library twice. This time it's ol-ext.js. Once you load it from https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/ol-ext/master/dist/ol-ext.min.js, and then again from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Viglino/ol-ext@master/dist/ol-ext.min.js. Please again, do first basic debugging youselves, you can't expect others to do it for you forever.